# Get all instances of primary keys of a table

Tags: postgresql, key, instances

This is a simple example of what I need, for any given table, I need to get all the instances of the primary keys, this is a little example, but I need a generic way to do it.

```
create table foo
(
 a numeric
,b text
,c numeric
constraint pk_foo primary key (a,b)
)

insert into foo(a,b,c) values (1,'a',1),(2,'b',2),(3,'c',3);
```

select  **<the magical thing>**

result

```
      a|b
   1 |1|a|
   2 |2|b|
   3 |3|c|
   ..   ...
```

I need to control if the instances of the primary keys are changed by the user, but I don't want to repeat code in too many tables! I need a generic way to do it, I will put **<the magical thing>**
 in a function to put it on a trigger before update and blah blah blah...

Comment: Is Java okay or do you want it as straight SQL?  Do you mean unique keys, candidate keys, or something else?

Comment: (fortunately) You cannot do that with just SQL.

Comment: @BradleyRoss yup, only sql and only i want to know the instances of the primary key of any given table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you must always provide a resulting type for a query. However, you can obtain the code of the query you need, and then execute the query from the client:

```
create or replace function get_key_only_sql(regclass) returns string as $$
select 'select '|| (
          select string_agg(quote_ident(att.attname), ', ' order by col)
          from pg_index i
          join lateral unnest(indkey) col on (true)
          join pg_attribute att on (att.attrelid = i.indrelid and att.attnum = col)
          where i.indrelid = $1 and i.indisprimary
          group by i.indexrelid
          limit 1) || ' from '||$1::text
end;
$$ language sql;
```

Here's some client pseudocode using the function above:

```
sql = pgexecscalar("select get_key_only_sql('mytable'::regclass)");
rs = pgopen(sql);
```

Comment: yeah, this work! my problem was i didnt know how to get the columns names of the primary keys of the given table, but you crack it! thank you

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I've done that with SQL in the past, but for Postgres I had used JDBC.